# Local ArcGIS Server REST services not loading in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

I'm developing with "ArcGIS API for Silverlight 3.2" and publish my map into ArcServer 10.2 on my local host and can load my own REST services with javascript perfectly.

However, when I try to load my own REST services from our ArcGIS Server map services the Silverlight Control will run, show the ESRI image in the bottom but no map.

My xaml code is :

```
<UserControl x:Class="CreatingAMap.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap">
        <esri:Map.Layers>
            <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="test2" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Electricity_WMS/MapServer" />              
        </esri:Map.Layers>
    </esri:Map>

</Grid>
```

and when i put my own REST address as URL attribute, i can see my map in design mode but i will run it, show the ESRI image in the bottom but no map.!!!

also when i use sample services in ArcGIS Sever like "SampleWorldCities" that it is in ArcServer 10.2 by default or use samples in ArcGIS Online my app run perfectly but when i use my services that i published its in ArcServer ,not working and show the ESRI image in the bottom but no map.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I don't think the  element is required.  Try it without that, e.g.:

```
<esri:Map x:Name="MyMap">
    <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="test2" Url="http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Electricity_WMS/MapServer" />
</esri:Map>
```

Comment: Tanks for your attention.I try it but it not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a sniffing tool like fiddler to see what's going on with http requests? It sounds like it might be a cross domain policy setting. As well, silverlight uses a client access policy xml file that might be a cause. Again, first things first, use a tool like fiddler to see what's going on with your service calls. Hope this helps.